# Do bitwise values have to be exponential?

Tags: .net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In all bitwise examples, I see values being incremented exponentially (1, 2, 4, 8, etc).  However, in the following Enum, I use 1, 2, 3, 4 (and pardon the VB, if you will):

```
<Flags()>
Enum BitWiseTest
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
End Enum
```

To my surprise, the following code works:

```
Dim TestBits As BitWiseTest

TestBits = TestBits Or BitWiseTest.One
TestBits = TestBits Or BitWiseTest.Two
TestBits = TestBits Or BitWiseTest.Three
TestBits = TestBits Or BitWiseTest.Four

Dim BitToRemove As BitWiseTest

BitToRemove = BitWiseTest.Two

TestBits = Not BitToRemove

Console.WriteLine(TestBits And BitToRemove)
```

Commenting out the line `TestBits = Not BitToRemove` will show you that not removing the bit will show you that it's still on.  Channging `BitToRemove = BitWiseTest.Two` to use another enum value will show you that it works for other bits, as well.

It appears to be working flawlessly, so what's up with the exponential incrementation of values that I am seeing everywhere regarding bitwise?

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you set both `One` and `Two`? Or when you set `Three` and unset `One`?

Comment: Ah, setting Three and unsetting One brokeded it!  I learned something with bitwise today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally two kinds of enums. For an enum:

1. One of the values is used.
2. A combination of values is used.

#### One of the values is used

In this case you can just number the enum members any way you like. You can even have two members with the same value if they mean the same. For example:

```
Enum Comparison
    None = 0
    CaseSensitive = 1
    IgnoreCase = 2

    Default = 1
End Enum
```

#### A combination of values is used

A value is now boolean: it is either *on* (used, specified) or *off* (not used or specified). This converts nicely to bits, which are 1 (on) or 0 (off). To be able to distinguish the values from one another, you *should* use powers of two. Then there is for any particular bit only one value that can set that bit on or off.

```
<Flags()>
Enum NumberStyles
    None = 0                    ' Binary:          0
    AllowLeadingWhite = 1       ' Binary:          1
    AllowTrailingWhite = 2      ' Binary:         10
    AllowLeadingSign = 4        ' Binary:        100
    AllowTrailingSign = 8       ' Binary:       1000
    AllowParentheses = 16       ' Binary:      10000
    AllowDecimalPoint = 32      ' Binary:     100000
    AllowThousands = 64         ' Binary:    1000000
    AllowExponent = 128         ' Binary:   10000000
    AllowCurrencySymbol = 256   ' Binary:  100000000
    AllowHexSpecifier = 512     ' Binary: 1000000000
End Enum
```

Now you can combine two values to get a new one, and you can distinguish the values:

```
Dim testBits As NumberStyles
testBits = NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier _
        Or NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite _
        Or NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite       ' Binary: 1000000011

' If (1000000011 And 1000000000) <> 0 Then
If testBits.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

And you can add those combinations to the enum too, if it makes sense:

```
<Flags()>
Enum NumberStyles
    ' ...
    Integer = 7                 ' Binary:        111
    Number = 111                ' Binary:    1101111
    Float = 167                 ' Binary:   10100111
    Currency = 383              ' Binary:  101111111
    HexNumber = 515             ' Binary: 1000000011
End Enum
```

---

### About your example

Look at the binary values of your example. Values `One`, `Two` and `Four` are powers of two, but `Three` is not. If I extend your example, maybe you can see the problem:

```
<Flags()>
Enum BitWiseTest
    One = 1     ' Binary:    1
    Two = 2     ' Binary:   10
    Three = 3   ' Binary:   11
    Four = 4    ' Binary:  100
    Five = 5    ' Binary:  101
    Six = 6     ' Binary:  110
    Seven = 7   ' Binary:  111
End Enum
```

Now, doing `Six Or Three = Seven`, which is usually not what you want. Also `value And Two` is `True` when `value` is `Three`, `Six` or `Seven`, which is also probably now what you want. The reason is that the one bit that is set in `Two` is also present in `Three`, `Six` and `Seven` due to how you chose the values.

Answer (score 3):

> It appears to be working flawlessly

It depends on what you mean by "flawlessly".

Do you *really* want `BitWiseTest.One` Or `BitwiseTest.Two` to equal `BitwiseTest.Three`? That's what you'll get at the moment, which isn't normally ideal... Typically you want the flags to be independent, which means that they need to be represented by independent bits in the binary representation - and that's precisely what you get by using values of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc.

Comment: As demonstrated by CodesInChaos' answer, it appears that it's not so much a matter of whether or not it's ideal as it is a matter of causing bitwise operations so simply not work properly.  Setting three and removing one then checking for three resulted in two when I would have expected it to result in three.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin the bitwise operations there are still working properly, you just made them do something that doesn't match your intentions

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: "ideal" was used somewhat sarcastically here - although there are certainly cases where you *do* want combinations. Look at `NumberStyles.HexNumber` for example. Bitwise operations "work properly" - in that they behave as expected when you understand what they do. But you do need to understand them first...

Answer (score 0):

They don't have to be exponential, there's no language limitation for that.

For most cases it makes sense to define them exponential so they are independent from one-another. In a *very* few cases you may benefit from combining the exponential *flag* values with predefined *state* values:

```
public enum KitchenState{
    NothingHappening = 0,

    PanOnStove = 1,
    StoveOn = 2,
    Preheating = 3,

    EggsInPan = 4,
    EggsCooking = 7, 
}
```

In this case Preheating and EggsCooking are *states* and PanOnStove, StoveOn and EggsInPan are *flags*. This is mostly a gimmick but it can come handy on occasion